# Explanation/suggestion for possibly accidental format of Windows 10 system drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd

A weird thing just happened to me on a spare laptop. It's a ThinkPad T560 that was running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

I was using it to simply initialize a USB drive with a router distro installation (OPNSense as it happens). I was using Rufus to do this, probably the most recent version.

So I started everything up and Rufus began writing to the correct USB key drive, but it looked like it was going to take awhile, so I walked away from it to do a few other things.

By the time I got back, the T560 was in some sort of boot loop trying to do the boot-from-network feature in the BIOS (which I never use).

I pulled the USB key and tried a few reboots on the ThinkPad, to no avail. It clearly looked like the SSD that used to have Windows on it was not being found or just had nothing bootable on it.

I was in a hurry and needed the USB key to fix something else, so I went off and worked on that and the USB key worked fine -- it had been written correctly by Rufus.

I'm now back on the T560 trying to figure out what happened to cause it to not only reboot but apparently get the OS overwritten.

I figure that maybe Rufus finished the USB key creation and automatically rebooted for some reason (though I don't think I requested that and don't even see such an option in Rufus). Then maybe the USB key (for OPNSense install) automatically booted and then automatically (with no user intervention because no one else was home!) started to overwrite my Windows install?

More importantly, since I've done nothing except launch a Windows 10 installer to attempt auto-repair (which was unsuccessful), what should my next steps be?

I've launched a couple of partition tools to try to take a look at the SSD drive and it appears it has 3 partitions on it (which I think might be the original state of it) but no filesystems seem to show.

What tools (preferably open source/free ones) should I use to evaluate this situation and possibly recover from it?

I don't have many data files I'm concerned about recovering but would really rather not have to run through a full re-install of Windows and the other software I had on here.  I don't think I made some huge mistake here so I'm hoping something like restoring/recovering a partition table or something might be enough to correct the issue, but I'm not particularly hopeful since I don't have much experience in data recovery (but do have plenty of general technical experience).

Comment: Working in IBM support for years (in the before times), here is one theory:  Just because a drive failed while playing solitaire, doesn't mean that solitaire killed your drive.  I realize that it is possible that your actions helped kick this off; however, it is also possible that the drive simply failed.  One other suggestion (if you continue to use SU).  We don't need a book.  We don't need to know how you were feeling or the dialog.  Only the facts.  This post should have been AT LEAST 50% smaller.

Comment: 1. Rufus doesn't have a feature to automatically reboot the machine it's running on. 2. Rufus cannot format a disk volume that isn't removable storage. 3. OPNSense does not automatically install without user intervention, even if it did, it wouldn't have booted to that environment due to preconfigured boot order.

Comment: @Ramhound -- I didn't know 2. for sure, but that's good to know, and 1. and 3. I did assume, that's why this mess is so confusing.  Thanks for confirming what I suspected.

Comment: _"I figure that maybe Rufus finished the USB key creation and automatically rebooted for some reason"_ Rufus won't do that. Source: I am the developer of Rufus, and there is nothing even remotely related to triggering a Windows reboot in its code. Something else must have triggered the reboot after Rufus was done creating the key. And Rufus has safety features that prevent it from ever being able to format/erase an internal drive, or its bootloaders, by mistake (including from an application bug), so it wouldn't have been able to alter your Windows drive. Could a Windows update be the cause?

Comment: @Akeo, thanks for taking the time to respond.  I still have no idea what the original cause was (I trust it was *not* Rufus) but have resolved the issue (see below answer to gapsf).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I don't think I made some huge mistake here so I'm hoping something like restoring/recovering a partition table or something might be enough to correct the issue...

Try to recover it with TestDisk. It is free opensource recovery tool.

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

> https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
> If you have lost partition or strange problem with your hard disk partitions, run TestDisk to recover your data. TestDisk detects numerous filesystem including NTFS, FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, exFAT, ext2, ext3, ext4, btrfs, BeFS, CramFS, HFS, JFS, Linux Raid, Linux Swap, LVM, LVM2, NSS, ReiserFS, UFS, XFS.
> TestDisk can also undelete files from FAT, NTFS, exFAT and ext2 filesystem.

Comment: I think you got downvoted because this answer - while helpful - is, at the end of the day, a link-only answer. It could be improved by adding some instructions on how to use Testdisk in a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

@gapsf, thanks!  I'd run across PhotoRec in my research on file recovery but knew that probably wasn't going to be something I needed since my problem seemed like a disk partition one.

I got TestDisk running from Ultimate Boot CD and with just a bit of fiddling around (the curses UI on TestDisk is great even when you're not sure just what to do) was able to browse files on the three partitions (all NTFS filesystems, on this Win10 install) and get TestDisk to re-write the partition table so that they would be recognized as usual by other tools.

Windows did not immediately boot after that, I did have to use some of the typical Windows recovery tools like bcdboot and bootrec.  I ended up having to rebuilt the BCD entries.

But now it's running as it was before, and everything seems corrected.  Thanks again to you and everyone else who read my question and responded.